# firefox history won't delete

Tags: firefox, history

I am trying to delete firefox history and it is hanging. Just trying to delete the "older than 6 months" folder and it hangs. Any other way to get at it?

thanks for your considered reply,
gm

Comment: You can delete the profile itself.  The location is documented on the Firefox website

Answer (score 1):

Run [**bleachbit**](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/download/windows) and tick the boxes under Firefox, then clean

Answer (score 0):

Found this in [a support forum](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=956855), worked for me:

> I used this to clear the history. Open History from the tool bar or ctrl+shift+H. 'single click' on one of the links to highlight it; click on 'Organize' in the top tool bar and select All; delete.
>   Long way around it but it works. I even have the history set to only retain for 'one' day, but that doesn't work either. Frustrating; should be a simple fix.